# Can't run ghci from terminal

Tags: haskell, ghci, manjaro

I'm trying to run ghci for a Haskell assignment for a project. However it gives me this error message:

```
/usr/local/haskell/ghc-8.2.1-x86_64/lib/ghc-8.2.1/bin/ghc: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried to make a symbolic libtinfo.so.5 using ln, but it still doesn't work. Entering 'locate libtinfo.so.5' gives me the following:

```
/usr/lib/libtinfo.so.5

/usr/local/haskell/ghc-8.2.1-x86_64/lib/libtinfo.so.5
```

I'm running Manjaro Linux.

Comment: Try `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/haskell/ghc-8.2.1-x86_64/lib ghc --interactive`

Comment: Sadly returns the same error message.

Comment: You might try using strace to see exactly which directories are being searched to see whether or not the linker is checking in the right places

Comment: It appears that Manjaro linux is based on Arch Linux.  I'm not sure how you have installed GHC, but there is a project called [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/), that, among other things, installs GHC for you automatically.  There have [been](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3509) [numerous](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/257) [bugs](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2712) over the past few months relating to the interaction of GHC, ncurses, and libtinfo.

Comment: I'm not sure if the three bugs I've linked to are related to your problem, but they seem relevant.  You may also want to try installing the `libtinfo5` package from AUR (assuming that Manjaro Linux also has something like AUR).  If that doesn't work, you may want to try installing the `ncurses-full` package from AUR.  If that also doesn't work, you may want to try using `stack` to install GHC.

Comment: @illabout why the heck would using stack to install GHC make a bit of difference here? It ends up using the default GHC installer under-the-hood.

Comment: One approach would be to use the AUR-installed GHC (it may not be as recent, but it is likely to be tested well). The other would be to see if you need to set the no-pie setting by editing  `usr/local/haskell/ghc-___/lib/ghc-___/settings` and changing the " compiler supports -no-pie" flag from "NO" to "YES".

Comment: @sclv I was under the impression that stack will install a GHC linked to different libraries based on the distro you are using it on.  For instance, I am pretty sure that something different is being done for arch linux.  I can't find the exact issue that talks about this, but I believe it can find found by following links from [here](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3509).  If all jortseljongen wants to do is use GHCi for an assignment, it might be faster installing it with stack than building GHC from source.

Comment: I'm not suggesting installing from source. I'm suggesting either using the AUR from Arch directly, which is the best way to install things on a distro (using the distro's own mechanisms) or using a GHC installer (i.e. from https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_8_2_2.html) directly. That installer is does not build from source. It is a binary installer that runs some scripts to configure things based on your system.

Comment: Installing the https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ncurses5-compat-libs/ compat  libs may  also help.

Answer (score 1):

Running `ghcup tool-requirements` to get a list of implicit dependencies GHC has, then installing them through my OS' default package manager, worked for me:

```
sudo apt install -y build-essential curl libffi-dev libffi7 libgmp-dev libgmp10 libncurses-dev libncurses5 libtinfo5
```

Don't ask me why it worked, or why `ghc` and `ghcup` couldn't detect those dependencies were missing, or why `ghcup` didn't ensure those dependencies were correctly installed, or why the error message was so utterly useless. I ***hate*** this part of programming so much.

Comment: Well, we could probably avoid "this part of programming" by using [Nix](https://nixos.org/) for everything.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I definitely the think OSes of the future will all use a functional-programming style approach to dependencies, program permissions, and program execution (I'm been dreaming of something like that for ages). I think it's an absolute disgrace the way package management, version control, security sandboxing, and a million other essential functions are handled by modern OSes. Sadly, Nix seems to only be a very small step in that direction I've been dreaming. I'll absolutely give it a try though, thanks for the reminder to give it a proper go!

Answer (score 0):

Run the following:

```
$ sudo pacman-key --refresh-keys
$ gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys C52048C0C0748FEE227D47A2702353E0F7E48EDB
$ yaourt -S ncurses5-compat-libs
```

Then try running GHCi